# Can only establish Microsoft JDBC Connection on localhost, not on Server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, ajax, jdbc

I have been using JDBC for about two months now in the development of a Java web application. I recently started migrating everything to a dev server but the web app crashes when it's run from the server (as opposed to when it's run from localhost, where it runs successfully), and I found the bug today. I have an ajax function calling a Servlet that contains:

```
try 
{           
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Drivers.MICROSOFT_INTEG.driverURL);
    response.getWriter().write("established connection");
    ...
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    response.getWriter().write("entered catch");
}
```

And so when I alert the 'data' that is returned by my Ajax success function I get "entered catch". The weird thing is that it works fine on localhost, so I don't think it has to do with the connection String or any part of the code really. Also, TCP/IP *is* enabled for my instance of SQL Express. I don't get any errors on my web console so it's tough to say what error it spits out. But it is definitely entering the catch. Any thoughts?

### Thanks!

UPDATE:

I changed my catch to:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    response.getWriter().write(e.getMessage());
}
```

and I get "This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionID:ce6e4873-127f-4b71-b6e2-8c853a1fa594"

Comment: what exception is throwing the method?

Comment: @JordiCastilla I added it in the update

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running on Linux? According [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6087911/edit) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication.aspx) there can be some issues about authentication:

> There are different versions of sqljdbc_auth.dll for different processor architectures (x86/x64/ia64).  Which one are you using on your SFS server?
>
> You must choose the one to match the architecture of the JVM under which SFS is running.  So, if you're running 32-bit Java on a 64-bit machine, you'll need the x86 version, not the x64 version.
>
> Also It might be worth taking a look at it's logs to see if anything helpful has been written to them.

There are many possible problems and solutions, so i recommend you take a [google look](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22this%20driver%20is%20not%20configured%20for%20integrated%20authentication) of your exception and compare with your client/server requirements.

Comment: No, I am running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. I already made sure I have the correct version of the sqljdbc_auth.dll